# Large firework display

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles

I'm creating a New Year's Eve firework display and so eventually want a couple of dozen fireworks to go off in quick succession. I've got a single explosion I'm happy with using a particle system on an icosphere, which uses a small icosphere with a coloured emitter material as its particle.

What I'd like to do now is duplicate that across the sky, varying the start frame, position, colour. Do you have any advice on the easiest way to do that other than to keep duplicating the object and particle system and manually changing them?

Comment: You can change size by randomly scaling icospheres. You can use the *Object Info* node to get random colors, though I'm afraid they will be randomized by individual particle, not by whole particle system. You will probably have to manually assign a different material to each sphere